# Rewrite rule to show maintenance page for IPs not in the list

Tags: .htaccess

I need to allow site access to only development team accessing from IPs `111.111.111.111` and `222.222.222.222` and for the rest of the visitors would like to show temporary maintenance page `brb.html`

I tried this with the following condition and rewrite rule and it got into a redirect loop. Any insights on how to make this work?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^222\.222\.222\.222
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^brb.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ /brb.html [R=307,L]
```

Note: IPs used above are not the real ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(222\.222\.222\.222|111\.111\.111\.111)
RewriteRule !^brb\.html$ /brb.html [R=307,L]
```

And test in a new browser.

`!^brb\.html$` in rewrite rule pattern will stop looping for you.

**SOLUTION:**

Because of CloudFlare I had to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-FOR}` instead of `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}`

Comment: Although it is re-directing, it is doing so for IPs in the `RewriteCond` as well :(

Comment: If IP is correct then it won't. Check in Apache log what client IP is logged and then use that IP here in logs.